# OpenLayers Scale calculation

Tags: openlayers-2

I'm trying to modify the scale calculation in OpenLayers. Looking at the code, I couldn't understand what is going in this piece of code:

scale = (this.map.getGeodesicPixelSize().w || 0.000001) *

```
                inches["km"] *OpenLayers.DOTS_PER_INCH;
```

especially what is getGeodesicPixelSize().w and 0.000001 representing?

Bellow is the full block of code

updateScale: function() {

```
    var scale;

    if(this.geodesic === true) {

        var units = this.map.getUnits();

        if(!units) {

            return;

        }

        var inches = OpenLayers.INCHES_PER_UNIT;

        scale = (this.map.getGeodesicPixelSize().w || 0.000001) *

                inches["km"] *OpenLayers.DOTS_PER_INCH;inches["km"]

    } else {
        scale = this.map.getScale();
    }

    if (!scale) {
        return;
    }

    if (scale >= 9500 && scale <= 950000) {
        scale = Math.round(scale / 1000) + "K";
    } else if (scale >= 950000) {
        scale = Math.round(scale / 1000000) + "M";
    } else {
        scale = Math.round(scale);
    }    

    this.element.innerHTML = OpenLayers.i18n("scale", {'scaleDenom':scale});
},
```